# RMagick installed but ZenTest doesnt work (Invalid gemspec error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I have Windows 7 64b and I want to use CarrierWave gem for working with file uploads. I needed to install RMagick... I have succesfully installed rmagick 2.13.2
but if I run

```
rails g uploader image
```

it thows me

```
Invalid gemspec in [C:/web/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specific
ations/ZenTest-4.9.2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
```

I thought that updating rubygem should help so I did it. Now I have rubygems version 2.0.3 (I hope its not a problem because downgrading like gem update --system 1.9.3 its not working)
I'm not able to uninstall ZenTest too... what I have to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled RailsInstaller and deleted Ruby folder, i deleted JRuby folder from C:\ (i had it for other work) and again installed RailsInstaller and now it works :-)